# Pins position for Cloth in Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

Can someone help! I am simulating a cloth attached to their 4 corners. I am trying to re-locate the 4 pins 0, 10, 88, 98 of the Cloth with an 10x10 array. I want to be able to place each Pin at a different position in x,y,z.
For this simulation I am using Three.js and Cloth.js.
Something similar to this example:
[https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_animation_cloth][1]

Here is my Code and also the Cloth code I am using.

```
var pinsFormation = [];
pinsFormation.push( pins );
pins = [ 0, 10, 88, 98 ];
var container, stats;
var camera, scene, renderer, clothGeometry, object;

init();
animate();
        function init() {
            container = document.createElement( 'div' );
            document.body.appendChild( container );
            scene = new THREE.Scene();
            scene.background = new THREE.Color( 0xFFFFFF );

camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 30, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 10000 );
camera.position.set( 1000, 50, 1000 );

// cloth
var material_wire = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color : 0x000000, side: THREE.DoubleSide, wireframe: true } );
clothGeometry = new THREE.ParametricGeometry( clothFunction, cloth.w, cloth.h );

object = new THREE.Mesh( clothGeometry, material_wire );  // clothMaterial
object.position.set( 0, 0, 0 );
scene.add( object );

            // renderer
            renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true } );
            renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
            container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
            var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera, renderer.domElement );
            controls.maxPolarAngle = Math.PI * 1.5; 
            window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );
        }

        function onWindowResize() {
            camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
            camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
        }
        function animate() {
            requestAnimationFrame( animate );
            var time = Date.now();
            var windStrength = Math.cos( time / 7000 ) * 20 + 40;
            windForce.set( Math.sin( time / 2000 ), Math.cos( time / 3000 ), Math.sin( time / 1000 ) )
            windForce.normalize()
            windForce.multiplyScalar( windStrength );
            simulate( time );
            render();   
        }
        function render() {
            var p = cloth.particles;
            for ( var i = 0, il = p.length; i < il; i ++ ) {
                clothGeometry.vertices[ i ].copy( p[ i ].position );
            }
            clothGeometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true;
            clothGeometry.computeFaceNormals();
            clothGeometry.computeVertexNormals();
            renderer.render( scene, camera );
        }

// cloth.js
var DAMPING = 0.03;
var DRAG = 1 - DAMPING;
var MASS = 0.1;
var restDistance = 25;
var xSegs = 10;
var ySegs = 10;
var clothFunction = plane( restDistance * xSegs, restDistance * ySegs );
var cloth = new Cloth( xSegs, ySegs );
var GRAVITY = 981 * 1.4;
var gravity = new THREE.Vector3( 0, - GRAVITY, 0 ).multiplyScalar( MASS );
var TIMESTEP = 18 / 1000;
var TIMESTEP_SQ = TIMESTEP * TIMESTEP;

    var pins = [];
    var wind = true;
    var windStrength = 2;
    var windForce = new THREE.Vector3( 0, 0, 0 ); 
    var tmpForce = new THREE.Vector3();
    var lastTime;

function plane( width, height ) {
    return function( u, v ) { 
        var x = ( u - 0.5 ) * width;
        var y = ( v - 0.1 ) * height; 
        var z = 0;
        return new THREE.Vector3( x, y, z );
    };
}
function Particle( x, y, z, mass ) {
    this.position = clothFunction( x, y ); // position
    this.previous = clothFunction( x, y ); // previous
    this.original = clothFunction( x, y );
    this.a = new THREE.Vector3( 0, 0, 0 ); // acceleration
    this.mass = mass;
    this.invMass = 1 / mass;
    this.tmp = new THREE.Vector3();
    this.tmp2 = new THREE.Vector3();
}

// Force -> Acceleration
Particle.prototype.addForce = function( force ) {
    this.a.add(
        this.tmp2.copy( force ).multiplyScalar( this.invMass )
    );
};

// Performs Verlet integration
Particle.prototype.integrate = function( timesq ) {
    var newPos = this.tmp.subVectors( this.position, this.previous );
    newPos.multiplyScalar( DRAG ).add( this.position );
    newPos.add( this.a.multiplyScalar( timesq ) );
    this.tmp = this.previous;
    this.previous = this.position;
    this.position = newPos;
    this.a.set( 0, 0, 0 );
};

var diff = new THREE.Vector3();
function satisfyConstraints( p1, p2, distance ) {
    diff.subVectors( p2.position, p1.position );
    var currentDist = diff.length();
    if ( currentDist === 0 ) return;
    var correction = diff.multiplyScalar( 1 - distance / currentDist );
    var correctionHalf = correction.multiplyScalar( 0.5 );
    p1.position.add( correctionHalf );
    p2.position.sub( correctionHalf );
}

function Cloth( w, h ) {
    w = w || 20;
    h = h || 20;
    this.w = w;
    this.h = h;
    var particles = [];
    var constraints = [];
    var u, v;
    // Create particles
    for ( v = 0; v <= h; v ++ ) {
        for ( u = 0; u <= w; u ++ ) {
            particles.push(
                new Particle( u / w, v / h, 0, MASS )
            );
        }
    }

// Structural
for ( v = 0; v < h; v ++ ) {
    for ( u = 0; u < w; u ++ ) {
        constraints.push( [
            particles[ index( u, v ) ],
            particles[ index( u, v + 1 ) ],
            restDistance
        ] );
        constraints.push( [
            particles[ index( u, v ) ],
            particles[ index( u + 1, v ) ],
            restDistance
        ] );
    }
}

for ( u = w, v = 0; v < h; v ++ ) {
    constraints.push( [
        particles[ index( u, v ) ],
        particles[ index( u, v + 1 ) ],
        restDistance

    ] );
}

for ( v = h, u = 0; u < w; u ++ ) {
    constraints.push( [
        particles[ index( u, v ) ],
        particles[ index( u + 1, v ) ],
        restDistance
    ] );
}
this.particles = particles;
this.constraints = constraints;
function index( u, v ) {
    return u + v * ( w + 1 );
}
this.index = index;
}

function simulate( time ) {
if ( ! lastTime ) {
lastTime = time;
return;
}

var i, il, particles, particle, pt, constraints, constraint;

// Aerodynamics forces
if ( wind ) {
    var face, faces = clothGeometry.faces, normal;
    particles = cloth.particles;
    for ( i = 0, il = faces.length; i < il; i ++ ) {
        face = faces[ i ];
        normal = face.normal;
        tmpForce.copy( normal ).normalize().multiplyScalar( normal.dot( windForce ) );
            particles[ face.a ].addForce( tmpForce );
            particles[ face.b ].addForce( tmpForce );
            particles[ face.c ].addForce( tmpForce );
        }
    }

for ( particles = cloth.particles, i = 0, il = particles.length; i < il; i ++ ) {
    particle = particles[ i ];
    particle.addForce( gravity );
    particle.integrate( TIMESTEP_SQ );
}

// Start Constraints
constraints = cloth.constraints;
il = constraints.length;
for ( i = 0; i < il; i ++ ) {
    constraint = constraints[ i ];
    satisfyConstraints( constraint[ 0 ], constraint[ 1 ], constraint[ 2 ] );
}

// Pin Constraints
for ( i = 0, il = pins.length; i < il; i ++ ) {
    var xy = pins[ i ];
    var p = particles[ xy ];
    p.position.copy( particles.original );
    p.previous.copy( particles.original );
}
}
```

Comment: 10x10 segments mean 11x11 vertices. [ 0, 10, 88, 98 ] = > [0, 10, 110, 120].

Comment: Yeah, your right. Any ideas how can I assign specific positions to those vertex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "pin" is just the index of one of the vertices.. so what you'll have to do is identify the vertex corresponding to the spot you want to pin.. you can get that from a raycast when the user clicks the mesh, or figure it our analytically.

Comment: Sorry I am not so experienced. I don’t know what is a raycast or to figure it analytically. Can you send me an example?

Comment: https://threejs.org/examples/?q=raycast

Some raycasting demos ^.

Basically a way of clicking a mesh with the mouse, and getting back the position and triangle of the mesh that was clicked.. from there you can figure out which vertex is closest to the hit point, then figure out the index of that vertex.. and that could become one of your "pins".


Figuring it out analytically, i basically mean trying or guessing what index could be the right one for the pins that you want. 

@RonMarcial